# Facebook SDK integration issue in Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am having following issue when refrencing com_facebook_android into my existing project.
I am attaching a pic for refrence.

This is the tutorial i am following. 
http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once again download Facebook SDK becoz their may be problem see http://postimage.org/image/f4tt8y94t/

EDIT : Deprecated

Comment: tell me exactly what u want to do after integration